# 's' case with getopt dosent print out the active files

Tags: c

This certain getopt case is supposed to be used as an ls (the unix/linux command) alternative that returns the active files but once compiled and ran nothing is returned in the terminal.

Here is the full code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#define DATA_SIZE 1000

void print_help(void)
{
    printf("Help\n");
    printf("> cast -d (deletes file)\n");
    printf("> cast -r (renames file)\n");
    printf("> cast -c (create new file)\n");
    printf("> cast -s (searches contents of file)\n");
    printf("________________________________________\n");
    printf("Find an error or a bug? please submit it in the issues section on github\n");
}

case 's': {
    int main(void)
    {
        DIR *directory;
        struct dirent *entry;

        directory = opendir(".");

        if (directory == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error reading directory\n");
            return 1;
        }

        while ((entry = readdir(directory)) != NULL)

            if (entry->d_type == DT_REG)
            {
                printf("file: %s\n", entry->d_name);
            }
    }
    if (closedir(directory) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error closing directory\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
          }
     }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int option_val = 0;
    int opt_delete = 0;
    int opt_help = 0;
    int opt_rename = 0;
    int opt_create = 0;
    int opt_search = 0;

    while ((option_val = getopt(argc, argv, "dhrcs")) != -1) {
        switch (option_val) {
        case 'd': {
        char filename[65]; //Hope your filename isnt bigger than this

    printf("Filename or path to file: ");
    scanf("%s", filename); // checks to see if your filename isnt bigger than specified

    if (remove(filename) != 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Errno: %d\n", errno);
      perror("Error msg");
    } else printf("%s, deleted.\n", filename);

            opt_delete = 1;
            break;

        case 'r': {
            char file[65], new[65];

            printf("File: ");
            scanf("%s", file);

            printf("New name: ");
            scanf("%s", new);

           if (rename(file, new) != 0)
         {
              fprintf(stderr, "Errno: %d\n", errno);
              perror("Error msg");
           } else printf("%s --> %s", file, new);
            opt_rename = 1;
            break;
        case 'c': {

        FILE *f = fopen("Castdocument.txt", "w+");
        
        fprintf(f, "Finished with maybe no errors? Rename this file to whatever you would like and change the filename extension with ""cast -r""");
            
        printf("File created! (Check your home directory for ""Castdocument.txt"" file and modify that to fit your needs)");

        fclose(f);

        opt_create = 1;

        case 'h': {
        print_help();
            opt_help = 1;
            break;
    default:; /* '?' */
            //print_help();
        }

      if (opt_delete) {
        printf("\n");
    } if (opt_rename) {
        printf("\n");
    }  if (opt_help)  {
         print_help();
    } if (opt_search) {
    printf("\n");
    } if (opt_create) {
        printf("\n");
           }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is the 's' case:

```
case 's': {
    int main(void)
    {
        DIR *directory;
        struct dirent *entry;

        directory = opendir(".");

        if (directory == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error reading directory\n");
            return 1;
        }

        while ((entry = readdir(directory)) != NULL)

            if (entry->d_type == DT_REG)
            {
                printf("file: %s\n", entry->d_name);
            }
    }
    if (closedir(directory) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error closing directory\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
          }
     }
```

I attempted to move the case out of the switch statement but to no avail.

Comment: (a) You can't have code like a `switch` statement that isn't *inside* a function. (b) How on earth do you think having your `main` inside a `case` is going to work? Looks like you need a decent C Programming Primer.

Comment: There's no way that could have compiled.

Comment: Don't include `getopt.h`; it's not portable. If all you need is the standard `getopt`, POSIX says you should be including `unistd.h`. Be sure to define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` at the top of the file or on the command-line, or else the behavior is undefined.